# Can't build or install GO tools binaries

Tags: go

I am trying to build some GO tools in my project. I first run

```
go get golang.org/x/tools/benchmark/parse
```

The folder/binary structure does appear correctly under

```
$GOPATH/src/golang.org/x/tools/benchmark/parse
```

I tried running: `go build golang.org/x/tools/benchmark/parse`

and

`go install golang.org/x/tools/benchmark/parse`

however the binaries still do not appear in my `$GOPATH/bin`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: benchmark/parse isn't a main package. There is no binary generated from that path.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/benchmark/parse  You probably want `go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/...`. That will fetch all of the 'official' go tools at once.

Comment: Also `$GOPATH/golang.org/x/tools/benchmark/parse` isn't a valid source path. The source should be in `$GOPATH/src`

Comment: @JimB Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't build benchmark/parse, but you can import it.

From [Godoc for Tools](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools):

> Package parse provides support for parsing benchmark results as generated by 'go test -bench'.

sudorandom's comment is right, [parse.go](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/benchmark/parse/parse.go) doesn't use `package main`, so it won't generate a binary, while you can use it within your own code with `import "golang.org/x/tools/benchmark/parse"`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to the whole GoLang scene and appreciate the answers to rookie questions like these. Part of the misunderstanding was that build didn't spit any kind of error out.